# Is it possible to install an application without going through the next next step?

Tags: c#, performance, file, download, installation

Well the question is quite self explanatory but ..
I want to create a program that when i execute it , it will download some files and then install them for example chrome. But how am i going to pass the next next phase of the installation ? I am using C sharp or Java. I have some code at the moment to download the file which doesnt :S

What i want it ultimately to do it : 
1) Download - Install Chrome
2) Enter the gmail acc ( proly java scrip ? )
3) The rest will probably be something similar.

```
        private void Download()
    {
        WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
        webClient.Headers.Add("user-agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; Windows NT 5.1; rv:1.9.2.4) Gecko/20100611 Firefox/3.6.4");
        webClient.DownloadFileCompleted += new AsyncCompletedEventHandler(Completed);
        webClient.DownloadProgressChanged += new DownloadProgressChangedEventHandler(ProgressChanged);
        webClient.DownloadFileAsync(new Uri("http://dl.google.com/update2/installers/ChromeSetup.exe"), Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop));
    }
```

I dont know if the download page blocks me coz of the client header or anything else..
Thank you before hand!

Answer (score 1):

Using pinvoke you can send shortcuts to the setup window handler by SendKey function.

Here is a sample code from [codeguru](http://www.codeguru.com/forum/showthread.php?t=468125). It uses [PostMessage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644944.aspx) function.

```
[DllImport("User32.Dll", EntryPoint = "PostMessageA")]
    static extern bool PostMessage(
        IntPtr hWnd, 
        uint msg, 
        int wParam, 
        int lParam
        );

    const uint WM_KEYDOWN = 0x100;

    const int WM_a = 0x41;
    const int WM_b = 0x42;
    const int WM_c = 0x43;


    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        //using Process.GetProcessesByName to get the handle we want  
        Process[] p = Process.GetProcessesByName("notepad");  
        IntPtr pHandle = p[0].MainWindowHandle;  

        //will write "abc" in the open Notepad window
        PostMessage(pHandle, WM_KEYDOWN, WM_a, 0);
        PostMessage(pHandle, WM_KEYDOWN, WM_b, 0);
        PostMessage(pHandle, WM_KEYDOWN, WM_c, 0);
    }
```